# Does there exist a non-open connected set where the derivative of $f$ vanishes without $f$ being constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, analytic-functions

Let $D \subsetneq \Bbb C$ be a non-open connected set and let $f : D \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ be an analytic function with $f'(z) = 0,$ for all $z \in D.$ Does it necessarily imply that $f$ is constant on $D?$

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinR I think the "non-open" part is key in this problem.  I don't know how you can prove this from the usual theorem on domains.  You can probably consider this one as "is open necessary?"  (that said, I'm not sure how to interpret "analytic on non-open set")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition analyticity of $f$ on $D$ means it is analytic in some open set containing $D$. If $D$ has more than one point then $D$ is uncountable. Hence it has  a limit point. Since the zeros of $f'$ have  a limit point we get $f'=0$ in the connected component of the domain that contains $D$. Hence $f$ is constant on $D$.

Comment: If I replace analyticity of $f$ on $D$ by differentiability of $f$ on $D$ does it still hold? Because I can't say then $f'$ to be analytic and hence can't apply identity theorem as well.

Comment: @mathmaniac. Differentiability at point requires the function to be defined in some open set containing the point.

Comment: But then can I apply identity theorem on $f'$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring The standard definition of analyticity on a set is differentiability on some open set containing the set.

Comment: Sir I am trying to find a function defined everywhere in the complex plane but differentiable only at points on the either axis (hence nowhere analytic) and the derivative vanishes at each of these points where it exists but the function is not constant on the real and the imaginary axes. Is it possible to construct such a function?

Comment: But it is constant in the real and the imaginary axes @Martin R.

Comment: At the moment I don't have an answer. Perhaps you could ask a  separate question and see if someone can come up with an  example. @mathmaniac.